# Shell: How do I get the last argument the previous command when it was detached?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-history, readline, line-editor

Within the shell, typing `ALT+.` or using `!$` recalls the last passed argument of the previous command.  I use this all the time, but how do you do that when you detached the previous command?

```
$ do-something foo a_long_file_name &
```

How do I get `a_long_file_name` on the prompt, and not the ampersand?

Answer (score 3):

`\e-\e.` (or pressing `-` and `.` while holding alt/option) inserts the second last word.

Similarly, `\e-2\e.` inserts the third last word, and `\e2\e.` inserts the third word.

Answer (score 3):

Using history expansion, you can access the words of the previous command with `!:n` where n starts at 0 with the command name. `!^` is equivalent to `!:1`. In this case, you want `!:2`

```
$ echo foo bar &
[1] 10750
foo bar
$ echo !:2
echo bar
bar
[1]+  Done                    echo foo bar
```

Comment: The Csh history mechanism doesn't replace the argument on the Bash command line, though.

Comment: True, it's a placeholder only.

Answer (score 2):

You do `$_`.

```
echo 'hey there' &
echo "$_"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
hey there
hey there
```

Comment: Does not work for me using `bash 4.3`.$ `echo 'hey there' &

hey there
$ echo "$_"

$`

Comment: Works without `&`, but not when running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

The answers of glenn and Lauri are correct, but they require too much typing IMO.
Finally I came up with the following solution: `C-j` looping through the arguments of the previous command (excluding the ampersand), from the last one to the first one. This is very practical! Here is how to do that:

Write the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cj_hist=$(builtin history | tail -n1)
cj_num=$(cut -f1 -d\  <<< $cj_hist)

if [[ $cj_old_num -eq $cj_num ]]
then
  cj_killw='\x17'
else
  cj_args=$(cut -f3- -d\  <<< $cj_hist)
  cj_args=${cj_args%&}
  cj_args=($cj_args)
  cj_cnt=0
  cj_killw=''
fi

[[ $cj_cnt -le 0 ]] && cj_cnt=${#cj_args[*]}
let cj_cnt--

if [[ $cj_cnt -eq -1 ]]
then
  bind '"\ez":""'
  # bind -m vi-insert '"\C-o":""'
else
  bind '"\ez":"'$cj_killw${cj_args[$cj_cnt]}'"'
  # bind -m vi-insert '"\C-o":"'$cj_killw${cj_args[$cj_cnt]}'"'
fi

cj_old_num=$cj_num
```

Put this in your ~/.bashrc:

```
 bind -x '"\ew": source ~/foo.sh'  # ~/foo.sh is the script's path
 bind '"\C-j":"\ew\ez"'
 # bind -x '"\C-h": source ~/foo.sh'      # vi-users: no mess
 # bind -m vi-insert '"\C-j":"\C-h\C-o"'  # with escapes
```

NB: Since we source the script, we have to use variable names that are not commonly used, hence the prefix `cj_`. Of course, you can use another prefix.

Comment: It makes me chuckle when 3 characters is too much typing. As soon as the previous command has more than 3 arguments, I win!!!1! :)

Comment: `C-j C-j C-j C-j` may be faster to type than `:!5` though, and I don't have to count the arguments. You know, I am doing silly things to type fewer characters or to give my brain a rest, such as: `alias l=ls` :-) Laziness is the biggest factor of progress.

Comment: Prefix your local variables with `local` to restrict scope; and since you're sourcing it, drop the `#!` line.